# PHP merge arrays based on matching value of a given index

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays like this :

**Array1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [Code] => 175
            [Date] => 2012-09-05 20:30:02.217
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Code] => 178
            [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217
        )

)
```

**Array2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Amount] => 1234
            [ID] => 101
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Amount] => 1342
            [ID] => 103
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Amount] => 0
            [ID] => 0
        )

)
```

I use this code to combine them based on the matching values of the ID index.

```
      $combined = array();
           foreach ($arr as $arrs) {
                   $comb = array('ID' => $arrs['ID'], 'Code' => $arrs['Code'],'Date' => $arrs['Date'],'Amount' => '');
                   foreach ($arr4 as $arr2) {
                       if ($arr2['ID'] == $arrs['ID']) {
                           $comb['Amount'] = $arr2['Amount'];
                           break;
                       }
                       else {
                        $comb['Amount'] = $arr2['Amount'];
                       }
                   }
               $combined[] = $comb;
           }
echo print_r($combined);
```

And here is the desired output I get from this code :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
            [Amount] => 1234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [Code] => 175
            [Date] => 2012-09-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 1342
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Code] => 178
            [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 0
        )

)
```

I want to optimize the code such that

```
$comb = array('ID' => $arrs['ID'], 'Code' => $arrs['Code'],'Date' => $arrs['Date'],'Amount' => '');
```

should be generated dynamically rather than hard coded.
And instead of `$comb['Amount'] = $arr2['Amount'];` I want code to automatically add all the other feilds to the first array where the ID matches.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: is it guaranteed that both arrays will have the same number of elements and each array will have a matching id in the other array?

Comment: @man0v yes both arrays will have same number of elements. But each array may not have matching id as in array 2 there is no entry for ID 109. I have posted the output I get in the question.

Comment: Advise what to do when there is a missing id in the other array. Do we ignore those? Or do we add them as single ids?

Comment: In that case see this part of the output  [2] => Array ([ID] => 109 [Code] => 178 [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217 [Amount] => 0)  The amount 0 is added for that ID of Array1

Comment: @AlivetoDie no, the elements may not have the same index in both arrays

Comment: you can play with my code to see the current output

Comment: @node_man  why 0 merged with 109 id in your expected output? what logic applied behind expected output? can you please explain?

Comment: if the ID's don't match then just take the Amount which will always be 0. Amount and  ID is 0 in Array2 because I have already recreated array2 to be of the same length as that of Array1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution to make it completely dynamic apart from `ID`, do like below:

```
$arr2 = array_column($array2, "ID");

$finalArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $arr){
    $key = array_search($arr['ID'], $arr2);
    if($key ===false){
        $key = array_search(0, $arr2);
    }
    unset($array2[$key]['ID']);
    $finalArray[] =     array_merge($arr,$array2[$key]);
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/1sDJs

Answer (score 4):

First use the ID as keys:

```
$arr1 = array_column($arr1, null, "ID");
$arr2 = array_column($arr2, null, "ID");
```

Then sort the key (to solve non-same original indexes:

```
ksort($arr1);
ksort($arr2);
```

Then use `array_map` as:

```
$res = array_map('array_merge', $arr1, $arr2);
```

Use `array_values` at the end to ignore the ID keys.

And if you have another array that include the ID field you can have the same logic on them - notice `array_map` can get more then 2 input array...

Reference: [array_column](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [array_map](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/CLV3I)

**Edited**:

Used template to fix issue where element are missing:

```
$keys = array_merge(array_keys($a[0]), array_keys($b[0]));
$template = array_combine($keys, array_fill(0, count($keys), null)); // create array of null for all keys
$a = array_column($a, null, "ID");
$b = array_column($b, null, "ID");
ksort($a);
ksort($b);


$res = array_map(function ($e1, $e2) use ($template){
    if ($e1 && $e2) return array_merge($e1, $e2); // if exist merge
    $e = $e1 ? $e1 : $e2; //get the exist element
    return array_replace ($template, $e); // add it
}, $a, $b);
```

Notice this solution will be valid to only 2 array - it can be generalize but I leave that to you

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/hnC20)

Comment: I had this. But sadly that's not what OP wants :|.

Comment: Also OP says that in both array id's can be at different indexes.

Comment: yes this doesn't give the output I mentioned in question

Comment: Added `ksort` to avoid the different indexes - and added live example - this look to me as the same output, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes - I did tried thinner version - but yes. And I did it dynamically. (my example include only 2 element and 2 field in each)

Comment: but i get an error if I add third element $a[] = ["ID" => 109, "CODE" => 2]; to the live example. Also in the output it prints a blank 3rd element.

Comment: please check the output in my question. It's a working example and the code is giving the correct output

Comment: In the question input both array has the same length - how can I know where to take the default value from? 
@DrakulaPredator - can you please show me? (I can find the difference)

Answer (score 1):

I tweak your code to do what you need, here is the complete code that worked for me:

```
<?php

$arr=Array(
     Array("ID" => 101, "Code" => 1075, "Date" => "2012-03-03 17:13:12.433"),
    Array("ID" => 103, "Code" => 175, "Date" => "2013-03-03 17:13:12.433"),
    Array("ID" => 109, "Code" => 178, "Date" => "2014-03-03 17:13:12.433")
);

$arr4 = Array(
    Array("ID" => 101, "Amount" => 1234),
    Array("ID" => 103, "Amount" => 1342),
    Array("ID" => 0, "Amount" => 0)
);

$combined = array();

foreach ($arr as $i => $arrs) {
    $combined['ID'][$i] = $arrs['ID'];
    $combined['Code'][$i] = $arrs['Code'];
    $combined['Date'][$i] = $arrs['Date'];

    foreach ($arr4 as $arr2) {
        if ($arr2['ID'] == $arrs['ID']) {
            $combined['Amount'][$i] = $arr2['Amount'];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($combined['Amount'][$i])) {
        $combined['Amount'][] = 0;
    }

}

echo print_r($combined);

?>
```

If you need further manipulation for different reasons, i suggest you read about `array_keys` and `array_values` methods, which are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$firstArray = [
    [
        'ID' => 101,
        'Code' => 1075,
        'Date' => '2012-03-03 17:13:12.433',
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 103,
        'Code' => 175,
        'Date' => '2012-09-05 20:30:02.217',
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 109,
        'Code' => 178,
        'Date' => '2012-07-05 20:30:02.217',
    ],
];

$secondArray = [
    [
        'ID' => 101,
        'Amount' => 1234,
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 103,
        'Amount' => 1342,
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 0,
        'Amount' => 0,
    ],
];

class DTO implements \Serializable
{
    /** @var int */
    private $id;

    /** @var int */
    private $code;

    /** @var string */
    private $date;

    /** @var int */
    private $amount = 0;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return [
            'ID' => $this->id,
            'Code' => $this->code,
            'Date' => $this->date,
            'Amount' => $this->amount,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @param array $serialized
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized): self
    {
        $this->id = $serialized['ID'];
        $this->code = $serialized['Code'];
        $this->date = $serialized['Date'];
        $this->amount = $serialized['Amount'] ?? 0;

        return $this;
    }
}

$thirdArray = [];
foreach ($secondArray as $item) {
    $id = $item['ID'];
    unset($item['ID']);
    $thirdArray[$id] = $item;
}

$thirdArrayKeys = array_keys($thirdArray);
foreach ($firstArray as &$item) {
    $id = $item['ID'];
    $dto = new DTO();
    $dto->unserialize($item);
    if (in_array($id, $thirdArrayKeys)) {
        $dto = $dto->unserialize(array_merge($item, $thirdArray[$id]));
    }

    $item = $dto->serialize();
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee72a1c89782f4eef25a1143816f237ca6af129c

Comment: but the Amount feild is missing in your output if the ID's dont match

Comment: I've updated code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee72a1c89782f4eef25a1143816f237ca6af129c