# Dynamically combine subsets of data with their header row, then group/merge/flatten datasets by a shared column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, optimization, grouping

I have an array of arrays like this which I get from a server's response:

```
$data = array (
    'data1' => array (
        0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'ID',
            1 => 'PinCode',
            2 => 'Date',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            0 => '101',
            1 => '454075',
            2 => '2012-03-03',
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
            0 => '103',
            1 => '786075',
            2 => '2012-09-05',
        ),
    ),
    'data2' => array (
        0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'Balance',
            1 => 'ID',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            0 => '4533',
            1 => '101',
        )
    ),
    'data3' => array (
        0 => 
        array (
            0 => 'Active',
            1 => 'ID',
            ),
        1 => 
        array (
            0 => 'Yes',
            1 => '101',
            ),
        2 => 
        array (
           0 => 'No',
           1 => '103',
        ),
    ),
);
```

On the above array I perform kind of a left join operation to get the final output below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [PinCode] => 454075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03
            [Balance] => 4533
            [Active] => Yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [PinCode] => 786075
            [Date] => 2012-09-05
            [Balance] => 0
            [Active] => No
        )
)
```

I will explain how I get the output.
In all the arrays `data1` , `data2` and `data3` the **first row is the name of the columns** and the **remaining rows contain the data for those columns**.
**Firstly I take the array whose length is maximum in the `$data` array**. Hence from `$data` I first select `data1` array as its length is 3.
Using the following code:

```
$data1=$data['data1'];
$columns_data1 = $data1[0];
for($i=1;$i<=(count($data1)-1);$i++)
    {
        $output_data1[] = array_combine($columns_data1,$data1[$i]);
    }
echo print_r($output_data1);
```

I get the output `$output_data1` like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [PinCode] => 454075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [PinCode] => 786075
            [Date] => 2012-09-05
        )

)
```

After this I perform the following operation on `data2` and `data3` arrays to make their **length equal to that of `data1 length - 1` i.e excluding the first row which contains column names**.

```
$data2=$data['data2'];
    $columns_data2 = $data2[0];
    for($i=1;$i<=(count($data1)-1);$i++)
    {
        if($i<count($data2))
        $output_data2[] = array_combine($columns_data2,$data2[$i]);
        else
         $output_data2[]=array_combine($columns_data2,array('0'=>'0','1'=>'0')); //add the value as 0 to the rows and make the length equal to that of data1. Here I've take index 0 and 1 because first row in data contains two index i.e Balance and ID.

    }
echo print_r($output_data2);
```

This code gives the following output for `data2` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Balance] => 4533
            [ID] => 101
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Balance] => 0
            [ID] => 0
        )

)
```

Similary for `data3` :

```
$data3=$data['data3'];
$columns_data3 = $data3[0];
for($i=1;$i<=(count($data1)-1);$i++)
{
    if($i<count($data3))
    $output_data3[] = array_combine($columns_data3,$data3[$i]);
    else
     $output_data3[]=array_combine($columns_data3,array('0'=>'0','1'=>'0'));

}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output_data3);
```

gives the output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Active] => Yes
            [ID] => 101
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Active] => No
            [ID] => 103
        )

)
```

Next I'll combine `$output_data1` and `$output_data2` :

```
$left_join_on = array_column($output_data2, "ID");
    $first_leftjoin_output = array();
    foreach($output_data1 as $values){
        $key = array_search($values['ID'], $left_join_on);
            if($key ===false){
                    $key = array_search(0, $left_join_on);
            }
            unset($output_data2[$key]['ID']);
            $first_leftjoin_output[] = array_merge($values,$output_data2[$key]);
    }

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($first_leftjoin_output);
```

gives the output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [PinCode] => 454075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03
            [Balance] => 4533
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [PinCode] => 786075
            [Date] => 2012-09-05
            [Balance] => 0 //added 0 to balance as ID 103 didn't existed in output_data2. just like a left join of sql
        )

)
```

Next I'll do a join on `$first_leftjoin_output` and `$output_data3`

```
$left_join_on_next = array_column($output_data3, "ID");
    $second_leftjoin_output = array();
    foreach($first_leftjoin_output as $values){
        $key = array_search($values['ID'], $left_join_on_next);
            if($key ===false){
                    $key = array_search(0, $left_join_on_next);
            }
            unset($output_data3[$key]['ID']);
            $second_leftjoin_output[] =         array_merge($values,$output_data3[$key]);
    }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($second_leftjoin_output);
```

This step gives the final output `$second_leftjoin_output` which I already mentioned at the beginning of the question.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [PinCode] => 454075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03
            [Balance] => 4533
            [Active] => Yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [PinCode] => 786075
            [Date] => 2012-09-05
            [Balance] => 0
            [Active] => No
        )

)
```

Hence this way I left joined all the three arrays based on matching `ID` field.
As you can see I'm doing all this in a hard coded way.
If my `$data array` contains `data4` then again I'll have add the code to get `$third_leftjoin_output`.

I want this process to be dynamic.

I want a dynamic solution such that I just have to pass the $data array and the name of the feild the left join is going to be based on.

Something like this :

```
$output = left_join_function($data,"ID");
```

and this function should return the mentioned output. Or any other better solution would be also very helpful.

I'm not able to figure out how this can be done in a neat way.

Comment: it seems like the only value that really needs to change is `ID` by your account. why don't you just do this: `array_column($output_data3, $2nd_param);` and `array_search($values[$2nd_param], $left_join_on_next);` .etc. where `$2nd_param` is `ID`?

Comment: I recommend you use my solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56559802/6487675 and with that, adding 3th or 4th array is easy

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can use a function (https://www.php.net/manual/de/functions.user-defined.php)

```
function foo($arg_1, $arg_2, /* ..., */ $arg_n)
{
    echo "Example function.\n";
    return $retval;
}
```

For you:

```
function dataJoinStep1($array)
{
    // Do something with your array, left join etc.
    return $array;
}
```

You can call the function in a loop (while/for/etc) `dataJoinStep1($data)`

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is robust enough to work on a dynamic number of data subsets, but it relies on the fact that all subsets are related by their `ID` value.

Iterate each group, separate the header data and combine it with subsequent rows within the group.

In the same loop, use first level keys to associate data from previously encountered groups (with the same first level key) and merge related data before pushing it into the result array.  When finished iterating, call `array_values()` to re-index the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DA1iV))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            $data,
            function ($result, $group) {
                $header = array_shift($group);
                $idIndex = array_search('ID', $header);
                foreach ($group as $row) {
                    $result[$row[$idIndex]] = array_merge(
                        $result[$row[$idIndex]] ?? [],
                        array_combine($header, $row)
                    );
                }
                return $result;
            },
            []
        )
    )
);
```